# Toggling Music On and Off Based on CheckButton

Tags: python, pygame, toggle, audio-player

I have a menu cascade that has a checkbutton for switching on/off background music to an app (Using python tkinter).

When the app is run (via root.mainloop()), the background music is already playing and the checkbutton has a tick next to it like I want (indicating its on).

When I toggle the checkbutton off the sound turns off due to the self.sound_off command.

The problem is when I click the button again (and the tick appears), the sound doesn't turn on. I realise this is because the command I have specified in checkbutton is command=sound.off(). But I'm not sure how to make it so that when the tick appears the sound plays(or unpauses) and when the tick isn't there the sound pauses.

```
# within def __init__(self, master) of the app
self.add_sound()

self._value = IntVar(value=1)

menubar = tk.Menu(master)
master.config(menu=menubar)
filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar)        
filemenu.add_checkbutton(label="Music", onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable= 
                          self._value, command=self.sound_off)


def add_soud(self):
    pygame.mixer.music.load("Sound.mp3")
    pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.2)
    pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

def sound_off(self):
    pygame.mixer.music.pause()

def sound_on(self):
    pygame.mixer.music.unpause()

#Am I supposed to have some sort of 'if' statement to check if the onvalue is 
#0 or 1?
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work

```
filemenu.add_checkbutton(label="Music", onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable= 
                      self.sound_value, command=self.sound_manipulation)
```

and

```
def sound_manipulation(self):
    if self.sound_value.get() == 1:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()
```